# GridView does not redraw when it's children are defined as class member

Tags: flutter, dart

I've encountered a problem when building a GridView widget.

I pass a list of Widgets to GridView constuctor and when the list is defined as local variable it works fine however when it's defined as class member it does not redraw.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();       //doesn't work when defined here

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('----------------> initState()');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyHomePage oldWidget) {
    print('----------------> didUpdateWidget()');
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _createWidget(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _counter++;
          });
          print('_counter $_counter');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createWidget() {
    print('_createWidget()');
    // List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();          //it works when defined locally
    widgetList.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      widgetList.add(Text('Item $_counter'));
    }

    return GridView.count(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: widgetList,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tested your code i found same output in both the case.

Comment: In such case i thought it may be the outdated emulator or old dart version however I checked it on two android emulators: Android 7.0 API 24 and Android 10.0 API 29. Dart is the latest version - 3.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should use "GridView.builder" in this situation.

```
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: widgetList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return widgetList[index];
  },
);
```

Comment: It works in both cases with GridView.builder but it does not explain why I can't use GridView.count

Comment: I'm not sure. However, I think that "GridView.count" expects a fixed value and "GridView.builder" expects a variable value.